# How much changing MySQL datadir from SSD Drive "C:/.." to HDD Drive "D:/.." will slow down the query processing speed?

Tags: mysql, performance, schema, windows, ssd

I am working on my local device and have created a schema that makes drive "C:/" (SSD) nearly full (it took up nearly 60 GB from the available space), so I think I should move the data to drive "D:/" (HDD) to free up some space in Drive "C:/" and be able to create more schemas..

The question that comes in my mind before changing `datadir` value in `my.ini` file (MySQL Server 5.5<sup>[1]</sup>) is that: I have many queries that take > 10 minutes to finish<sup>[2]</sup>, so, does moving the data to an HDD Drive will make the execution time a lot longer than before?, If so, I would not move the data but look for another way to free up the space and be able to create more schemas!

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I am using [UMLS](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/licensedcontent/umlsknowledgesources.html) and [restricted](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/implementation_resources/scripts/README_RRF_MySQL_Output_Stream.html) to use MySQL Server 5.5

<sup>[2]</sup> Therefore, I am intrested in the reading speed more than the writing speed.

Comment: Only practrical tests may answer.

Comment: That link warns that 5.6 uses more disk space.  If that is the worst problem, surely you have enough disk space to do an upgrade?  There are, on the other hand, significant advantages in using InnoDB, even on 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

- It depends.
- HDD may be 10 times as slow, but you may not see that much difference.
- If the data is well cached, there could be very little difference in speed.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Is the dataset most of that 60GB?  How much RAM do you have?
- Show us some queries.
- Let's focus on that 10-minute query -- there may be a way to speed it up significantly -- regardless of the underlying disk.

So...  Yes, the 10 minutes may turn into 100.  But, we may be able to drop it down to 1 minute with some optimizations.

And...  Other queries may or may not be noticeably slower; it depends on too many things to predict.